# PhpMyadmin run on local working but deploy to digital ocean can't login to phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, phpmyadmin, digital-ocean

```
version: '3'
services:
  php:
    build: ./docker/php
    volumes:
        - ./:/usr/share/nginx/www
    working_dir: /usr/share/nginx/www
    env_file:
      - ./development.env
    networks:
      - bridge

  nginx:
    build: ./docker/nginx
    links:
        - php
    volumes:
        - ./:/usr/share/nginx/www
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - php
    networks:
      - bridge

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    env_file:
      - ./development.env
    depends_on:
      - php
    networks:
      - bridge

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:5.1-apache
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
      - PMA_HOST=mysql
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - bridge
      
networks:
    bridge:
        external: true
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSSlN.png)

I used `docker-compose` above to work with my local machine after deploying to DigitalOcean. I try to login to phpMyAdmin but cannot access.

This is the message displayed to me:

```
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
```